# How to fix ec2 instance when I can't login via ssh after installing clamscan/clamav?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, server, clamav

After installing clamscan clamav on ubuntu 18.04 aws ec2 instance I can't login to my aws server with ssh. Neither my website on that server shows up on browser. I have rebooted but not working. How do I fix this?
[image]

Comment: Waht is your instance type? Seems you have exhaustion its ram or disk space.

Comment: t2 micro it's with the free tier

Comment: Try upgrading your instance to b better one. Off course anything other than t2.micro wont be free. t2.micro has only 1GB of ram, and poor CPU. Your workload may require more.

Comment: looks like it. Thanks for helping out

Comment: No problem. If you don't mind, I will provide an answer with some links and extra info.

Answer (score 0):

Common reasons for [instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/monitoring-system-instance-status-check.html) are `Exhausted memory` and  `Corrupted file system`.

Since you are using **t2.micro**, which only has 1GB of ram, and by default 8GB disk, its possible that your instance is simply too small to run your workloads. In such a situation, a common solution is to upgrade it to, e.g. t2.medium (2GB of RAM), but such change will be **outside of free-tier**.

Alterantively, you can re-reinstall your application on new t2.micro, but this time setup [CloudWatch Agent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Install-CloudWatch-Agent.html) to **monitor RAM and disk use**. By default these things are not monitored. If you monitor them on a new instance, it can give your insights about how much ram, disk or other resources, are used by your applications.

The metrics collected in CloudWatch will help you judge better of what causing the freeze of your instance.